# In which referenceContainer of product page we add block for custom rich snippets of current product?

Tags: magento2, blocks, containers, rich-snippets

I have to extend default rich snippets for products. For this I have my script in .phtml file as:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
"@context": "http://schema.org/",
"@type": "Product",
<?php if ($block->nameEnabled()) { ?>
"name": "<?php echo $_products->getName(); ?>",
<?php } ?> <?php if ($block->imageEnabled()>0) { ?>
"image": [
<?php if($block->imageEnabled()==1) { ?>
"<?php echo $imageurl['0'] ?>"
<?php } ?>
<?php if ($block->imageEnabled()==2) { ?>
"<?php echo $imageurl['1'] ?>"
<?php } ?>
<?php if ($block->imageEnabled()==3){ ?>
"<?php echo $imageurl['2'] ?>"
<?php } ?>
], <?php } ?>
<?php if ($block->desEnabled()==1) { ?>
"description": "<?php echo $_products->getShortDescription(); ?>",
<?php } ?>
<?php if ($block->desEnabled()==2) { ?>
"description": "<?php echo $_products->getMetaDescription(); ?>",
<?php } ?>
<?php if ($block->getBrand()) { ?>
"brand": {
        "@type": "Thing",
        "name": "<?php echo $brandName = $block->getBrand();?>" 
    }, <?php } ?>
    <?php if ($block->skuEnabled()) { ?>
"sku": "<?php echo $_products->getSku(); ?>" ,<?php } ?>

"offers": {
<?php if ($block->priceEnabled()) { ?>
"@type": "Offer",
<?php if ($block->currencyEnabled()) { ?>
"priceCurrency": "<?php echo $block->getCurrencyCode(); ?>",<?php } ?>
"price": "<?php echo $_products->getFinalPrice(); ?>"
<?php } ?>
}
}
</script>
```

In which referenceContainer this block should be added so that snippets can be seen in https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using json, ‘head.additional’ will work.

Comment: @RamaChandranM This is a direct and exact answer to the question.

Comment: Thanks @shawnfor a reply. Human error always occurs :(. I think you may be explain some detail it will helpful for other :)

Comment: Thanks for response @ShawnAbramson. I used "head.additional" but Google structure data tool cannot read snippets. On the other hand, i used "content" referenceContainer and Structure data testing tool is reading richsnippets. But I have read in Google developers guide that richsnippets should be added in header of the page. So which will be the right referenceContainer to implement this ?

Comment: This should work, I've used this block quite a bit with no issues. I assume that you flushed the cache before checking right? Could you post the XML that you are using to update the layout with your code?

Comment: well I am working in developer mode and my cache is disabled. Here is XML file at: vendor/module/etc/frontend/frontname_index_index.xml
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
  
  
 xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <body>
            <referenceContainer name="content">
                <block class="vendorname\modulename\Block\RichSnippets" name="RichSnippets1" template="vendorname_modulename::RichSnippets.phtml"/>
            </referenceContainer>
        </body>
    </page>

Comment: Your file is in the wrong location. Do any other layout directives that you use in that file work? For example, try <referenceBlock name="header" remove="true" /> and see if your header disappears.

Comment: can you post the real path to your file, relative to your project route?

Comment: I think you are asking about layout file ? It is place at vendor_name/module_name/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml
right ?

Comment: Yes. What is "vendor/module/etc/frontend/frontname_index_index.xml ". I don't recognize it

Comment: It was unwanted file i just recognized. For updating layout, which one file is recommended? vendor_name/module_name/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml OR vendor_name/module_name/view/frontend/layout/default.xml

Comment: default.xml will make it work for all pages. catalog_product_view.xml only works on product pages.